# PRESS Stat Error - Can't use NA as column index with `[` at position 1

Tags: r, regression

I have build the regression model as follows:

```r
model = lm(delay ~ industry + public + quality + finished, data)
```

and I am trying to run the PRESS statistic function from the `qpcR` package

```r
> press = PRESS(model, verbose = FALSE)
```

but I am getting the error -

> Error: Can't use NA as column index with `[` at position 1.
> In addition: Warning message:
> 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 40 rows

The thing is that I do not have NAs and have not specified newdata

```r
> which(is.na(data))

integer(0)
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.